# mui clip TextField background fill to border

Tags: material-ui

For TextFields in MUI, the background seems to extend beyond the border, if there is one.  Here's an example:
[image: MUI TextField with border]

Is there any way to clip the background color to the border?

Thanks!

... We managed to get it working by using OutlinedInput instead of TextField.  Here's an example:

```
function App() {
   return (
      <>
         <TextField
            sx={{
               variant: 'outlined',
               backgroundColor: '#ddddff',
               borderRadius: '16px',
            }}
         />
         <OutlinedInput
            sx={{
               backgroundColor: 'pink',
               borderRadius: '8px',
            }}
         />
      </>
   );
}
```

Here's what gets displayed:

[image]

Still curious if there's some prop for TextField that we're missing.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you share detailed it would be easy to understand. Specifying exact borderRadius may help you , check padding also.

```
<TextField sx={{ backgroundColor: 'red', borderRadius: '5px' }} />
```

[image]